# getting error as Unable to autoload constant UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error while visiting `/users/new` in Rails 4 as `Unable to autoload constant UsersController, expecting /app/controllers/users_controller.rb to define it`.

Here is the controller code

```
    class UserController < ApplicationController
     def new
      @user = User.new
     end

     def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user]).permit(:email,  :password,:password_confirmation)

      respond_to do |format|
       if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_path, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
       else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
      end
    end 
  end
```

And the view for `new.html.erb` I have is:

```
  <h1>Sign up</h1>

  <%= form_for(@user)  do |f| %>

    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being      saved:</h2>

        <ul>
          <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
     </div>
   <% end %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create my account" %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

`User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :pledges
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment: Change `UserController` to `UsersController` (by convention in rails, controller names should be the pluralized form of the resource).

Answer (score 26):

Rails expects controller names to be pluralized.  The very first line of the the first file contents you posted is written as singular:

In `/app/controllers/users_controller.rb` you have:

> class **User**Controller < ApplicationController

Instead, it should be:

> class **Users**Controller < ApplicationController

This [Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) provides an example for defining a resource in your routes file. Further, there is an informational note that explains that defining a routes with the `resource` method will always map to the pluralized name of the controller.

This is the informational note from the guide.

> Because you might want to use the same controller for a singular route (/account) and a plural route (/accounts/45), singular resources map to plural controllers. So that, for example, resource :photo and resources :photos creates both singular and plural routes that map to the same controller (PhotosController).

source: [Resource Routing: The Rails Default](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

Comment: Can you please cite your source of "Rails expects controller names to be pluralized."

Comment: @yekta I added some additional info with a source. This emphasizes the fact that pluralized controllers are convention.  The info is buried in a side note. Pluralization is implied throughout the guides, and Rails itself.  It is possible to override the default and use a singular controller.

Comment: Thanks for the source.  Pluralizing did not resolve my issue though.  In my case I was using `unloadable` in the ApplicationController, removing it resolved it.

Comment: I just have to change from singular to pluralize in controller name and it works!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my route had a trailing backslash, that was causing this error:
`get '/badges/' => 'insights#badges'`

Changing this to this, works!
`get '/badges' => 'insights#badges'`